# I would like drop a constraint if it exists. Is this possible with alembic?

Tags: postgresql, alembic

If I try drop an non-existing constraint:
In revision file

```
op.drop_constraint('exists_in_some_db_fkey', 'table', type='foreignkey')
```

I got:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject)
constraint "exists_in_some_db_fkey" of relation "table" does not exist
[SQL: 'ALTER TABLE extensions DROP CONSTRAINT exists_in_some_db_fkey'] 
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

It's our fault, we have some corrupted database, but if we could drop constraint checking IF EXISTS, it could solve our problem.

We cannot change our models recently.

Comment: is it mandatory to do it on alembic (that I do not know) or can you use a plpgsql script (in this case I may have your solution)?

Comment: We are handling and migrating our databases with alembic, so we have to use it. We have some own tools built on alembic api, so we can impelment a new operation, but we don't want reinvent the wheel if it not necessary.

Comment: Sorry to read that. I can answer to your post with a plpgsql script of few lines that will do the trick, but I know nothing about Alembic ;)

Comment: @Jaisus thank you very much. I'll use alembic api to run some raw sql. I can't modify the database except with alembic.

Comment: Can you with Alembic run directly plpgsql script? Or use psql command?

Comment: Not really (or I don't know), but I can execute raw sql, so I think using plpgsql will be over kill...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192438/discussion-between-charisz-and-jaisus).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Alembic you always have an option to execute an SQL statement manually like this:

```
op.execute("ALTER TABLE new DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS parent_id_f")
```

See [Alembic Operation Reference: execute](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.execute)

Comment: This answer helped me figure out my issue. Actually I dropped a column that the constraint used, this seems to have dropped the constraint too. So in my next Alembic revision line when it tries to drop the constraint, if failed, because constraint doesn't exist anymore.